# Change position of fixed element to click point

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to create a popup for some of my links`(.aj_load)`  here is my code

```
$('.aj_load').live('click' , function(e){

    $('#aj_popup').remove(); // delete old popups 
    var x = e.pageX ; 
    var y = e.pageY ;

    var template = '<div class="popup"  id="aj_popup" style="display:none">'+
            '<div class="main"><span class="msg"></span>'+
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="attach" onclick="slideup();"></a>'+
            '<br style="clear:both;" /></div></div>' ;

    $('body').append(template);
    $('#aj_popup').css('left' , x ).css('top' , y ).fadeIn();
    return false;
})
```

so it works fine except it doesn't appear where i click . how should i do the positioning ? 
here is the css for popup

```
.popup {
    background:#333;
    color:#333;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:8px;
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:3000;
    opacity: .95;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=95)";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write CSS as key value pairs and see how that goes. Looking in firebug should help

```
$('#aj_popup').css({
       'left':'x',
       'top': 'y'

}).fadeIn();
```